# MongoDB aggregate $group and $match with group result

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection as follows

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("553b2c740f12bb30f85bd41c"),
    "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",
    "order_id" : "PW_BarclaysTrades60530",
    "ticket_id" : "PW_BarclaysTrades.60530",
    "basketid" : "TESTBASKET-1428483828043",
    "date_sent" : ISODate("2015-04-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "destination" : "BarclaysTrades",
    "order_price" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "order_quantity" : 4000000.0000000000000000,
    "order_type" : 1.0000000000000000,
    "parent_quantity" : 250000000.0000000000000000,
    "time_sent" : "09:03:48",
    "side" : 1,
    "tif" : "0",
    "execution_id" : 88939,
    "date_recvd" : ISODate("2015-04-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "exe_quantity" : 50000.0000000000000000,
    "time_recvd" : "09:03:48",
    "execution_price" : 2.5000000000000000,
    "execution_type" : 1
}
```

I would like to get the documents whose execution_price greater than  average(execution_price) for each destination in the collection

Trying to aggregate as follows:

```
db.orders_by_symbol.aggregate( [
{ $limit:300000 },
{ $match:{ destination: "PAPER" } },
{ $group:{_id:{Destination:"$destination"},avg_exec_price:  
              {$avg:"$execution_price"} ,"data":{"$push": "$$ROOT"}}},
{$unwind:"$data"},
{$match:{execution_price:{$ne: "$avg_exec_price"}}},
{$project:{_id:0,symbol:"$data.symbol",destination:"$data.destination",
          execution_id:"$data.execution_id",
          exec_price:"$data.execution_price",
         avg_ex_price:"$avg_exec_price"}}], 
{allowDiskUse:true})
```

Getting the following Result

```
{

    "result" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",

            "destination" : "PAPER",
            "execution_id" : 89109,
            "exec_price" : 6.5000000000000000,
            "avg_ex_price" : 95.0747920857049140
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",
            "destination" : "PAPER",
            "execution_id" : 89110,
            "exec_price" : 6.0000000000000000,
            "avg_ex_price" : 95.0747920857049140
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",
            "destination" : "PAPER",
            "execution_id" : 89111,
            "exec_price" : 6.5000000000000000,
            "avg_ex_price" : 95.0747920857049140
        }
```

But when I change the '$ne' operator with  '$gt' no result is being produced. Both exec_price and avg_ex_price are double datatype.Not sure why it is not working as expected.

Comment: I think your condition `{$match:{execution_price:{$ne: "$avg_exec_price"}}}` not working may be you should write `{$match:{data.execution_price:{$ne: "$avg_exec_price"}}}`

Comment: Yes. That was a type error.

Comment: Queries like that will make your servers cry. You should avoid aggregation framework like the plague if you want your application to scale.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Using MongoDB Server 3.6 and newer:**

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "destination": "PAPER" } },
    { "$facet": {
        "average": [
            { "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "avg_exec_price": { "$avg": "$execution_price" }
            } }
        ],
        "data": [
            { "$project": { 
                "_id": 0,
                "symbol": 1,
                "destination": 1,
                "execution_id": 1,
                "execution_price": 1
            } }                   
        ]
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "average": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$average", 0] }
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "data": { 
            "$filter" : {
                "input": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$data",
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": {
                            "symbol": "$$el.symbol",
                            "destination": "$$el.symbol",
                            "execution_id": "$$el.symbol",
                            "exec_price": "$$el.execution_price",
                            "avg_exec_price": "$average.avg_exec_price"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "as": "doc",
                "cond": {
                    "$gt" : [ 
                        "$$doc.exec_price", 
                        "$$doc.avg_exec_price"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } },  
    { "$unwind": "$data" },  
    { "$replaceRoot": {  "newRoot": "$data" } }
];
```

---

For MongoDB versions which do not support the above operators and pipelines, use the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator to create an additional field that stores the comparison of the two fields via the [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) aggregation operator:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$match": {
        "destination": "PAPER"
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "avg_exec_price": { "$avg": "$execution_price" },
        "data": { "$addToSet": "$$ROOT" }
    } },
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "data": 1,
        "avg_exec_price": 1,            
        "isGreaterThanAverage": { 
            "$gt" : [ "$data.execution_price", "$avg_exec_price" ] 
        }
    } },    
    { "$match": {            
        "isGreaterThanAverage": true
    } },
    { "$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "symbol": "$data.symbol",
        "destination": "$data.destination",
        "execution_id": "$data.execution_id",
        "exec_price": "$data.execution_price",
        "avg_ex_price": "$avg_exec_price"
    } }
];
```

Now to test the above aggregation, suppose you have the following minimum test case collection:

```
db.test.insert([{
    "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",    
    "destination" : "PAPER",    
    "execution_id" : 88939,    
    "execution_price" : 1.8
},
{
    "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",    
    "destination" : "PAPER",    
    "execution_id" : 88921,    
    "execution_price" : 6.8
},
{
    "symbol" : "USD/GBP",    
    "destination" : "foo",    
    "execution_id" : 88955,    
    "execution_price" : 3.1
},
{
    "symbol" : "AUD/GBP",    
    "destination" : "PAPER",    
    "execution_id" : 88941,    
    "execution_price" : 1.1
},
{
    "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",    
    "destination" : "PAPER",    
    "execution_id" : 88907,    
    "execution_price" : 9.4
}]);
```

Running the above aggregation

```
db.test.aggregate(pipeline);
```

will produce the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",
            "destination" : "PAPER",
            "execution_id" : 88907,
            "exec_price" : 9.4,
            "avg_ex_price" : 4.775
        }, 
        {
            "symbol" : "EUR/GBP",
            "destination" : "PAPER",
            "execution_id" : 88921,
            "exec_price" : 6.8,
            "avg_ex_price" : 4.775
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much chridam.
I wonder why such a complex way to compare like this.Is there any other approach to achieve it.

Comment: @sasidharan No worries :-) I'm afraid that's one of the many complex ways in MongoDB aggregation framework, you will have to use different [**aggregation pipeline operators**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: we are planning to use java for application development. And we planned to do more aggregation on  mongodb collection.Clueless what would be the best way to achieve aggregation, as simple average and compare is looking complex.Appreciate your thoughts and suggestions
PS : The above query takes around 30 seconds for jus 2.5 million documents.I dont think its desirable.Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: In your planning, you should have a deep understanding of your application’s aggregation queries. Before you build the aggregation pipelines, map out the types of queries you will run so that you can build optimal and appropriate aggregation pipelines that does the job. Also consider the size of document affects the aggregation performance, the bigger the document the more IO is required to load it, even if the allocation is contiguous on the hard drive.

Comment: Hi Chirdam , The above aggregate query takes 2 mins to return the result .We have  10 million documents as of now in our collection. I have index on destination column too. What could be the reason for slowness and is there a way to reduce the throughput time.Appreciate if you can suggest some ideas

Answer (score 2):

After reading your questions you should use [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) in your aggregation as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "destination": "PAPER"
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$destination",
    "avg_exec_price": {
      "$avg": "$execution_price"
    },
    "data": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$data"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "check": {
          "$cond": [{
              "$gt": ["$data.execution_price", "$avg_exec_price"] // check in $cond if execution_price gt avg_exec_price
            }, "$data", ""] //push data if true else blank 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$data"
}, {
  "$match": {
    "data.check": {
      "$exists": true, // check data.check not empty or blank
      "$ne": ""
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "data": "$data.check"
  }
}).pretty()
```